# How does one write extconf.rb files when one extension includes header files from another?

Tags: c++, ruby, rubygems, extconf.rb

This is a follow-up question for: [Multiple Ruby modules under one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701611/multiple-ruby-extension-modules-under-one-directory)

What happens if these extensions include each other? For example, you have the following structure:

```
ext/foo
ext/bar
```

In `ext/bar/bar.h`, you have a

```
#include "foo.h"
```

`foo.h` and `foo.cpp` compile to form `foo.o`, to make life a little more complicated.

Finally, it is necessary that foo and bar be separate extensions.

How is this managed? I can't figure out how to add `../foo` to the search path for `bar.h`, primarily. Symbolic links seem hack-ish.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a mkrf_conf.rb file that does one then the other

https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/gem